# Why I cannot ssh when i add my VM's port to the bridge?

Tags: networking

I am a noob in networking and recently i started with my professional career. Please help me going in this domain and also my question might be silly too, pardon me for that.

Here goes my problem

I have a windows OS host and I am using an Oracle VM for hosting my VMs. I have a requirement to create two virtual interfaces in VM and also create a bridge in my VM. The primary interface of the VM is NATed to my host and this is also the wireless interface used for internet connectivity. Now the actual problem is, when I create my two virtual interfaces I am adding them to the bridge. When I try to add the VM interface (internet) to the bridge, i am loosing my internet access and there will be no IP to the VM interface. I am accessing my VM through SSH and this is closing when I add VM's internet interface to the bridge.

Can anyone help me explain why this is happening?
Also, any alternate way where I can add my interface of VM and still obtain seamless internet connection?

Comment: If the bridge status changes, there are messages in the kernel log. Can you check with `dmesg`?

Comment: It looks like an End-User question, which is off-topic for ServerFault.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the input. I am now able to bridge all the interfaces and i can have seamless SSH connectivity and internet connectivity.